# What is the best way to structure maven projects to make a client jar?

Tags: maven

New to maven here...coming from the ant world

I need to create a client jar with a few files that will give my client the ability to write to my Db and make rest calls to my services.
These are mainly classes that wrap a Rest connection and db client.

Is it possible to produce this artifact as a side effect of my main maven project ? 
Eg: main project produces a bundle when I run mvn package, but I'd like to produce the client jar by providing some other parameters....

Comment: Maven has a standard structure.  You have to conform to that.   The standard Maven lifecycle includes package; that's where you have the choice of how to package your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Maven way is "one project, one jar". This means that the cleanest way to achieve your goal is to set up a multi-module project where you have one module for your "normal" jar and one for your "client" jar. But there are other possibilities:

1. If you are talking about an ejb, you can use the maven-ejb-plugin and create a client artifact. Unfortunately, both artifacts then share the same pom (and, therefore, the same dependencies).
2. You can use the maven-assembly-plugin to assemble a set of files and deploy them as side artifact (same problem as in (1)).
3. You can use the maven-install-plugin and maven-deploy-plugin to install/deploy entirely different artifacts along with your main artifact. These artifacts need to be created before, e.g. by a custom maven plugin.

Comment: None of these 3 will create a runnable jar.

Comment: Where does the OP say that the jar should be runnable?

Comment: You are right, I have runnable jars on my mind.  Crap answer.

Comment: It does not have to be a runnable jar.... It needs to be a jar that a client java app can pull out of a maven repository...where it is deployed

Comment: @KaPr So, does my answer help you?

Comment: @JK, ty I have accepted the answer. However could you elaborate on 2. and 3. preferably with examples.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is a multi-module maven project.

The structure goes like this:

```
-- Parent Module
----- Child 1 Module
----- Child 2 module
```

Here you can have all your code/files of your main app in `child 1` module and put all the code/files for the client in the `child 2` module.

The parent module is just an aggregator which produces an artifact of type `pom`. Whereas each of your child modules will produce individual `jars`. 
You can then you  the second jar in your client.

For a detailed understanding how multi-module project works, check this [link](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).